# invalid Client for exchange code _ identityserver3 _ AppAuth

Tags: identityserver3, appauth

I'm using `AppAuth` framework for authentication in my `Swift` app, I can login but after login and coming back to my app, I can't exchange the code and get error invalid client.

My client configuration is:

```
var client = new Client
{
    ClientId = "IOS.Client",
    ClientName = "IOS Client",
    RedirectUris = { "com.mysite.accounts:/oauthredirect" },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code, //AuthorizationCode
    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "offline_access" },
};
```

I set `ClientSecret (SHA-256)` and my `ClientId` is ok but I get error invalid client.

I checked my logs and there is an error: **secret validators could not validate secret**

what's wrong?

Comment: your `RedirectUris` list probably doesn't match the redirect url passed on the authentication request.  You would need to post or look at IdenityServer's logging to confirm.

Comment: My `RedirectUris` is matched. and I confirmed with IdenityServer's logging and it's ok. but my `ResponseType` was `code`, is it true?

Comment: I think `code` for `ResponseType` is ok

Comment: The Identity Server log will contain the error and reason why it is rejecting the request. If you need more help then include the Identity Server's log for the  request

Comment: My log like this [link](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/28#issuecomment-364084225) my grant is `GrantTypes.Code` so after login I receive a code, now I should exchange code and get my claims and etc

Comment: of course my error in the log is **secret validators could not validate secret**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using IdentityServer3 and AppAuth you should not use special characters in `ClientSecret` and set your grant `AuthorizationCodeWithProofKey`.

this [link](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/276#issuecomment-410873214) is useful

Answer (score 0):

IIRC in IS3 you had to set a client secret. We didn't allow empty ones.

Either you set a secret on client and server, or upgrade to IS4 - IS3 is deprecated since quite some time.

Comment: Thanks, @leastprivilege, I'm using IdentityServer3.AdminUI for create `Client` and set `ClientSecret` with **SHA-256** but I have this error again **secret validators could not validate secret** in my logs.